Multimedia coauthoring tool for comparing vacation destinations
Regularly I need to work out various vacation destination options with family and friends.
Are there any good tools to do this?

Spreadsheet: it is mostly suitable for tabular data but cannot include any multimedia experience easily
Document: it is mostly suitable for including images, text, simple tabular data. But cannot sort

Neither of these have any advanced integration with the vacation provider's websites. It would be cool to be able to browse the photo materials of the vacation option, descriptions, any additional details easily. Integrated with a maps provider to easily calculate distance to home, or explore the target environment more.
